# How to restrict content, search result by users origin

Tags: django, restriction, cross-origin-read-blocking, siteorigin

I hope someone would be able to give an answer or suggestion for the following.

I have an application (Django/bootstrap/postgres) that contains books from in different languagues i.e. English, Arabic, Hindi, Bengali. I would like to restrict or control to view, search based on the users's origin.

As an example, if an user logged in from UAE or Saudi Arabia, he will be able to search only all the books in English and Arabic like if someone logged in from India, he will be able to see books in Hindi and English.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can use a third party app like https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip?lang=en to do this.

Comment: You use the IP geolocation django library in https://djangopackages.org/packages/p/django-ip2location/ to detect geolocation information by IP address.